# thinktecture identity server v3 managing users in Asp.Net Identity v2

Tags: c#, asp.net, thinktecture-ident-server

I want to use Identity Server v3 as a central authentication point for several internal web apps and I want to use Asp.Net Identity 2 as my repo for users and associated claims. I already have the two wired up together and I can see the Asp.Net Identity database created and populated when I authenticate with one of the social providers.

**Update**:
I can't get the Identity Manager UI to render. When I try to navigate to `https://localhost:44333/#/users/create`, it just displays the content of `/index.html`
The Thinktecture Identity Manager packages have been installed as required but I can’t find my way to the UI.

here is my Configuration method from the Startup class in my Host project:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       app.Map("/core", coreApp =>
            {
                var factory = new Thinktecture.IdentityManager.Host.AspNetIdentityIdentityManagerFactory("AspId");
                coreApp.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerConfiguration()
                {
                    IdentityManagerFactory = factory.Create,
                });

                var idsrvOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    IssuerUri = "https://idsrv3.com",
                    SiteName = "Thinktecture IdentityServer v3 - beta 3",
                    Factory = Factory.Configure("AspId"),
                    SigningCertificate = Cert.Load(),

                    CorsPolicy = CorsPolicy.AllowAll,
                    CspOptions = new CspOptions 
                    {
                        ReportEndpoint = EndpointSettings.Enabled,
                    },

                    AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions 
                    {
                        IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders,
                    }
                };

                coreApp.UseIdentityServer(idsrvOptions);
            });
```

This is probably very simple. Any help greatly appreciated.
Scott

Comment: You've seen [the sample](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity/tree/master/source/Host)?

Comment: yes, but when any attempt to get to /#/users/create just fetches the content of /index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my url should have been `/core/#/users/create`. It works now.